# Junit is unable to fetch value from local.settings.json using System.getenv

Tags: java, junit

Get value from local.settings.json

```
String url = System.getenv("SCRUBBER_DATA_API");
```

Junit is throwing below error while running the code - File - **UploadConsumptionTest.java**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at net.scorpiogroup.pool.pnp.functions.uploadconsumptionfunction.Uploadconsumption.getScrubberData(Uploadconsumption.java:319)
        at net.scorpiogroup.pool.pnp.functions.uploadconsumptionfunction.Uploadconsumption.lambda$run$8(Uploadconsumption.java:217)
        at java.util.HashMap$EntrySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1699)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
        at net.scorpiogroup.pool.pnp.functions.uploadconsumptionfunction.Uploadconsumption.run(Uploadconsumption.java:192)
        at net.scorpiogroup.pool.pnp.functions.uploadconsumptionfunction.UploadconsumptionTest.testUploadConsumptionTxnAndConPPSAndConsAssesAndPoolDaysWithSucc(UploadconsumptionTest.java:337)
```

local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
              "SCRUBBER_DATA_API": "*apiString*"
    }
},
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 8991,
    "10.80.20.5": 8991,
    "CORS": "*"
  }
}
```

If i replace 'System.getenv("key")' with a particular string value then its not giving error.

Comment: I've never heard that `System.getenv()` reads a "local.settings.json". Why do think the java runtime should read "local.settings.json"?

Answer (score 0):

You can read json file like this from resources.

```
InputStream inJson = UploadConsumptionTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/local.settings.json");
```

You have to put your json file in `test/resources/`. Otherwise it will not work.

If you want to convert inJson to your object, then you can use Jackson or gson as per your need.

i.e

```
YourObj obj = new ObjectMapper().readValue(inJson, YourObj.class);
```